# Some counter examples in group theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

In this question, which we flag it as a community wiki question,   we search for  a  big list of groups $G$  which can not be isomorphic to a structure mentioned in $i.$ for  some  $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,6 \}$

1. The homeomorphism group of a  topological space $X$.
2. The automorphism group of a (not necessarily finite  dimensional) Lie algebra.
3. The automorphism group of a coalgebra.
4. (Assuming $G$ is a Lie group) The isometry group of a Riemannian manifold.
5. The automorphism group of another group.
6. The automorphism group of a ring.

Comment: Every group $G$ is the group of homeomorphisms of a topological space $X$.  Let $X$ have as point set $\{t_g | g\in G\} \sqcup \{u_{g,h},v_{g,h}, w_{g,h} | (g,h) \in G\times G\}$.  Define the topology to be the finest topology satisfying the following specialization conditions:  for every $(g,h)\in G\times G$, impose $u_{g,h}$ specializes to $t_g$, $v_{g,h}$ specializes to $u_{g,h}$, $t_g$ and $t_h$, and $w_{g,h}$ specializes to $v_{g,h}$, $u_{g,h}$, $t_g$, $t_h$ and $t_{g\cdot h}$.

Comment: Do you mean any structure or a structure?

Comment: @YiftachBarnea  thank you for your comment. i revise the question.

Comment: @JasonStarr  could you pleae more explain on thi topology?any reference?I there obstruction to find  a  compact hausdorff space?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  "could you pleae more explain on thi topology?"  I would like to recommend that you use the spell checker that is built into the MO comments system.  A subset $U$ of $X$ is open with respect to the topology I mention if and only if it satisfies all of the following conditions: for every $(g,h)$ in $G\times G$, (a) if $U$ contains $t_g$ then $U$ contains $u_{g,h}$, (b) if $U$ contains $t_h$ or $u_{g,h}$, then $U$ contains $v_{g,h}$, and (c) if $U$ contains $t_{g\cdot h}$ or $v_{g,h}$ then $U$ contains $w_{g,h}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for your comment. As you can guess the "s" character in my keyboard had some problem and I was not aware of that. Any way, is there an obtruction to have compact  Haudorff space  X with Homeo(X) isomorphic to G?

Comment: For (5), $\mathbb{Z}$ works. I think also any cyclic group of odd (prime?) order. The idea is to note that $G/Z(G)$ embeds into $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, and hence $G$ is abelian (standard undergrad exercise). Such a group always has an automorphism of even order, assuming AOC (less standard exercise, not sure of level), a contradiction.

Comment: user1729: $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group with no automorphism of even order. But of course its automorphism group is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ either. Your argument shows that $\Aut(G)$ cannot be an abelian non-trivial group with no elements of order two. So for example any non-trivial finite abelian group of odd order is ruled out.